# Grails Application Image Path?

Tags: image, grails, directory

I am new in grails , I am trying to make an app that provide upload image from the users, and i want to store the image URL in database and want to store the image in a directory so that if i want to show in gsp the uploded image what is the way , I tried to use img src="${ assetPath(src: 'product/' + it.img_url)} to get the image , it works perfectly , Here product is a directory to save image in
"grails-app\assets\images\product" directory , and it work perfectly when i heart-coded copy image in product directory , but i want to let the user to upload image and also save in product directory. Is is right approach to save image in assets\image path or i should save image in web-app path, If i wrong what is the way to upload image in a directory and what is the way to show in gsp page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is right approach to save image in assets\image path or i should save image in web-app path

No, it doesn't make any sense to save the images within the web application itself, because the images will be lost when you redeploy the application. Instead, save them somewhere on the file system, e.g. `${HOME}/images`

Answer (score 1):

you should make a `/tmp` folder on the fly when the images arrives at your controller as follows.

```
environments {
    development {
        uploadFolder = "c:/temp/upload/"
    }
    test {
        uploadFolder = "c:/temp/upload/"
    }
    production {
        uploadFolder = "c:/temp/upload/"
    }
}
```

///on your controller you can save it using ur env settings

```
 documentInstance.fullPath = grailsApplication.config.uploadFolder + documentInstance.filename
            file.transferTo(new File(documentInstance.fullPath))
```